# iOS restore password in login box from keychain

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, keychain, keychainitemwrapper

I am saving username/password to keychain like so:

```
KeychainItemWrapper *keychainItem = [[KeychainItemWrapper alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"YourAppLogin" accessGroup:nil];

[keychainItem setObject:usernameField.text forKey:(__bridge id)(kSecAttrAccount)];
[keychainItem setObject:passwordField.text forKey:(__bridge id)(kSecValueData)];
```

then I retrieve the username password:

```
NSString *username = [keychainItem objectForKey:(__bridge id)(kSecAttrAccount)];
NSString *password = [keychainItem objectForKey:(__bridge id)(kSecValueData)];
```

then I want to auto put them in the username and password login box if the user checked remember me:

```
if ([_rememberMeSwitch isOn]) {
    usernameField.text = username;
}

if ([_rememberMeSwitch isOn]) {
    passwordField.text = password;
}
```

This works fine for username, but password is apparently being saved in the keychain as nscfdata, because when I try to insert password into passwordField.text I get:

```
[__NSCFData _encodingCantBeStoredInEightBitCFString]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

Is what I am trying to do just considered bad practice or is there an easy way around this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The docs are clear on it:
kSecValueData should be NSData / CFDataRef => so **you have to convert your string to data**

### to store it

convert your password text to NSData

```
NSData *pwdData = [passwordField.text dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

---

### to read it

convert the NSData to your password

```
NSData *pwdData = [keychainItem objectForKey:(__bridge id)(kSecValueData)];
NSString *password = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:pwdData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
passwordField.text = password;
```

Comment: Thanks. Worked great. Although I'm not sure what docs you're talking about. Never could find any documentation that said what you said. And every example I found online was storing password as string.

Comment: keychain services reference, kSecValueData: "The corresponding value is of type CFDataRef." ;) -- glad it worked out though